# Closed form of Sum of Choosing k elements from n elements

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

given  $P_{k}=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{i}^{k}  \ \ $ and $\ \ S_{k}= \sum \prod \alpha _{i} $ for  Newton's Identities

Then , $P_{2} = S_{1}P_{1} - 2S_{2}$

$P_{3} = S_{1}P_{2} - S_{2}P_{1} + 3S_{3}$

If I'm not misunderstood, $S_{2}$ is refers to sum of $n$ elements choosen for $2$ elements

Example ,  for set  $\left \{  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....,n \right \}$

that, closed form is$ \ \ S_{2} =  \frac{1}{24} n\left ( n^{2}-1 \right )\left ( 3n+2 \right )$

The problem is how can I find  closed   $S_{3},S_{4},S_{5},.....$   of that set?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your definition of $S_k$, what is the range of summation and product?

Comment: It's hard to be describe, $S_{1} =  a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+....+a_{n}$ 
,

$S_{2}=a_{1}a_{2}+a_{1}a_{3}+....+a_{2}a_{3}+a_{2}a_{4}+...+a_{n-1}a_{n}$

Comment: I think your $S_k$ are the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), usually referred to as $e_k$, and you want a closed form for $e_k(1,2,\dots,n)$.